# how to make condition for the List view from JSON

Tags: java, android, json, listview

i want to make listview where the listview data only coming from the name of "windy",from my json file.  can someone tell me where's my error ?
i make a condition in my json array to put in listview.
it should be show all the data from json and put it in the listview because (x == y) is right, but nothing happen , only empty listview.
when i make System.out.println(x +" "+ y); to make sure there's no empty, it show the value of x and y that is windy and windy, and from the condition i make it should show the the listview only the name of windy. but when i make (x!= y) it show all the data from json to listview.
thank you so much guys.

this is the part code of my conditian i make.

```
for(int i = 0; i < str_json.length(); i++){
JSONObject ar = str_json.getJSONObject(i);
String x = ar.getString("nama");
String y = "windy";
System.out.println(x +" "+ y);

//the conditon that i mean. 
//when i make if(x!=y), it show all the data from json to listview, not only "windy" 


if( x == y){

HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

String nama = ar.getString("nama");
String judul = ar.getString("judul");
String komen = ar.getString("komen");
String jawaban = ar.getString("jawaban");
String created_at = ar.getString("created_at");


map.put(tanya_nama, nama);
map.put(tanya_judul, judul);
map.put(tanya_komen, komen);
map.put(tanya_jawaban, jawaban);
map.put(tanya_waktu, created_at);

data_map.add(map);
```

this is the full code.

```
public class semuatempat extends ListActivity {

static String tanya_nama = "nama";
static String tanya_judul = "judul";
static String tanya_komen = "komen";
static String tanya_jawaban = "jawaban";
static String tanya_waktu = "created_at";

JSONArray str_json = null;
public String lo_Koneksi,isi ;

 // Search EditText
 EditText inputSearch;
 //Listview Adapter
 SimpleAdapter adapter;

 ListView lv;

private ProgressDialog pDialog;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data_map = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>  ();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.utama);

    Koneksi lo_Koneksi = new Koneksi();
    isi = lo_Koneksi.isi_koneksi();
    new AmbilData().execute();

}



class AmbilData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(semuatempat.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("loading ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {


        String link_url = isi+"komentar.php";
        JSONParsena jParser = new JSONParsena();
        JSONObject json = jParser.AmbilJson(link_url);

        try {
            str_json = json.getJSONArray("komentar");
            DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

            /**
             * Hashmap to load data from the Sqlite database
             **/
             HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
             user = db.getUserDetails();



             for(int i = 0; i < str_json.length(); i++){
                JSONObject ar = str_json.getJSONObject(i);
                String x = ar.getString("nama");
                String y = "windy";
                System.out.println(x +" "+ y);

                if( x == y){

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                String nama = ar.getString("nama");
                String judul = ar.getString("judul");
                String komen = ar.getString("komen");
                String jawaban = ar.getString("jawaban");
                String created_at = ar.getString("created_at");


                map.put(tanya_nama, nama);
                map.put(tanya_judul, judul);
                map.put(tanya_komen, komen);
                map.put(tanya_jawaban, jawaban);
                map.put(tanya_waktu, created_at);

                data_map.add(map);
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println(" cacad ");
                }

             }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {

                 adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        semuatempat.this, data_map,
                        R.layout.list_item, new String[] { tanya_nama, tanya_judul, tanya_komen,tanya_jawaban,tanya_waktu}, 
                        new int[] {R.id.nama, R.id.alamat, R.id.lat,R.id.lng,R.id.waktu});
                setListAdapter(adapter);

            }
        });
```

[image: empty listview]
[image: the result of System.out.println(x +" "+ y);]

Comment: `x` and `y` is String so try to use `equals` instead of `==`

Comment: Also, you have `protected String doInBackground()` but you are returning null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with the string compare function you have written :

```
x == y
```

Replace this with:

```
if (x.equals(y))
```

as x and y are strings.

Answer (score 0):

Change your

`if( x == y)`

to

`if( x.equals(y))` because you are comparing String.

Then in your AsyncTask, maybe you should change,

`class AmbilData extends AsyncTask(String, String, String)`

to

`class AmbilData extends AsyncTask(String, String, HashMap<String, String>) {`

In method doInBackground

```
 protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
    // rest of your method

    return map;
  }
```

Change onPostExecute method to:

```
protected void onPostExecute(HashMap<String,String> map) {
// adapting your hashmap to listview
    }
```

I've not tested it yet. But, it should work.